# "Framing not allowed" when using back button or re-opening closed tab in google chrome when logged in

Tags: bug, login

First: I **only** have this issue on security.stackexchange.com, not on other sites (at least not on the few that I have tried), and only if I'm logged in.  I get the "Framing not allowed" error message when doing some pretty "normal" browsing.  The fact that it only happens for me on security.stackexchange.com when logged in makes me suspect that it is a bug and not just a quirk of my browser, hence why I'm here.  Specifically, I get that error message (followed by a page refresh and normal site operation) if I do one of the following two things:

1. Go to security.stackexchange.com, click on any question, and then hit the back button in my browser (it also happens if the back button takes me back to a previous question instead of the site home page).
2. Be on the security main page or any question page, close the tab, and then use chrome to re-open the most recently opened tab.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Chrome 62 (yes, a bit old).  Some notes:

1. I **do not** have this same problem on Chrome on my phone.
2. I **do not** have this problem if I am not logged in

Comment: If it only happens at Security, shouldn't you be asking this at Security Meta?

Comment: @JasonBassford I did: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/149676  They suggested I ask here :)

Comment: Ah, interesting.